# Return true/false on searching multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following multidimensional $array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [domain] => example.tld
            [type] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [domain] => other.tld
            [type] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [domain] => blaah.tld
            [type] => 2
        )

)
```

I simply want to recursively search all the arrays on both key and value, and return true if the key/value was found or false if nothing was found.

Expected output:

```
search_multi_array($array, 'domain', 'other.tld'); // Will return true
search_multi_array($array, 'type', 'other.tld'); // Will return false
search_multi_array($array, 'domain', 'google.com'); // Will return false
```

I've figured out a ugly-ugly method to search against the domain against all keys with this function:

```
function search_multi_array($search_value, $the_array) {
    if (is_array($the_array)) {
        foreach ($the_array as $key => $value) {
        $result = search_multi_array($search_value, $value);
        if (is_array($result)) {
            return true;
        } elseif ($result == true) {
            $return[] = $key;
            return $return;
        }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        if ($search_value == $the_array) {
        return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone do better and match both against the key and value in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't go beyond those 2 levels, flipping keys/merging makes life a lot more pleasant:

```
<?php
$data = array
(
    '0' => array
        (
            'domain' => 'example.tld',
            'type' => 2
        ),

    '1' => array
        (
            'domain' => 'other.tld',
            'type' => 2,
        ),

    '2' => array
        (
            'domain' => 'blaah.tld',
            'type' => 2
        )
);
$altered = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive',$data);
var_dump($altered);
var_dump(in_array('other.tld',$altered['domain']));
var_dump(in_array('other.tld',$altered['type']));
var_dump(in_array('google.com',$altered['domain']));
```

---

To go beyond 2nd level, we have to loop once through all the nodes:

```
$option2 = array();
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data)) as $key => $value){
        $option2[$key][] = $value;
}
var_dump($option2);
```

Comment: This is doing exactly what I am after. Care to explain why this won't work for more than 2 levels?

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a reverse mapping from [domain] => [indices] and from [type] => [indices]. It's probably not going to save you much unless you do lots of searches.

(hint: you probably want to wrap it into a class to prevent inconsistencies in the mappings)

also, anytime you see something like this:

```
if ($search_value == $the_array) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

you can always turn it into:

```
return $search_value == $the_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

`function search_mutli_array($SearchKey, $SearchValue, $Haystack)
{
    $Result = false;
    if (is_array($Haystack))
    {
        foreach ($Haystack as $Key => $Value)
        {
            if (is_array($Value))
            {
                if (search_mutli_array($SearchKey, $SearchValue, $Value))
                {
                    $Result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if ($SearchKey == $Key && $SearchValue == $Value)
            {
                $Result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $Result;
}`